# CakePHP download file error

Tags: cakephp, download

So basically I am trying to download a file.

I Have the action:

```
public function getfile() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $accesskey = 'mrPQVeJF8VFXpSq';
        $data = $this->File->find('first', array('conditions' => array('File.accesskey =' => $accesskey)));   

        $filepath = substr($data['File']['path'], 17);

        $this->response->file($filepath, array('download' => true, 'name' => $data['File']['name']));

         return $this->response;
    }
```

this throws an error : (i guess the line with $this->response->file())

> Fatal Error Error: Class 'File' not found  File:
>   C:\wamp\www\project\lib\Cake\Network\CakeResponse.php  Line: 1347

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `File` is an [Utility of cake](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html#file-api). So, using it as a model will probably give you trouble. I recommend you change it. Read more about reserve cake and php words [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288864/cakephp-call-to-undefined-method-find/24308073#24308073). That may be the cause of your error.

And the other cause of that error is that you are not in FilesController, and are trying to call the `Find` model there. for that read how to load models from other controllers (look for `ClassRegistry::init` or `$this->loadModel()`.

I'm just guessing here, because your are "guessing the line giving trouble is `$this->response->file()`". You may get a more accurate response if you do not guess and debug exactly what line is giving you that error.